# Is that possible to deploy Laravel web application to shared hosting using GitHub Action & GitHub FTP Deploy?

Tags: laravel, github, deployment, ftp

Is that possible to **deploy** the **Laravel** web application to **shared hosting** using GitHub Action & GitHub FTP Deploy? If possible how should I change the.github\workflows\master.yml?

```
on: 
  push:
    branches:
      - master
name:  Deploy website on push
jobs:
  web-deploy:
    name:  Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name:  Get latest code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    
    - name:  Sync files
      uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@4.2.0
      with:
        server: ${{ secrets.ftp_server }}
        username: ${{ secrets.ftp_username }}
        password: ${{ secrets.ftp_password }}
        server-dir: /
```

Comment: CI/CD is a hard to configure, and you should test how the pipeline works after each step. No one will do this work for you. But in general, I would tell that Laravel is not working best on shared hostings, mainly because most of them do not provide SSH access, and you will probably end up having a lot of troubles while resolving issues related to path-sensitive settings.

Comment: Hey. Thank you for the helpful guide. I try to do that but I understand it will waste my time. Thanks again.

Comment: Did you try it before asking?

Comment: Yes. I I tried to a lot. But could not success. I only could done deploy simple html page using github. But in the GitHub FTP Deploy package has option such as npm run, instal like wise. That's why I thought laravel application also may can deploy using that. Any way now I am going to buy laravel forge and vps host. It will easy for me.

Comment: Yes, not only is it possible it is pretty easy to get set up. Laravel is fine on shared hosting. I have been using shared hosting with Laravel for years. But, your question doesn't have enough details for us to help you. For example, what isn't working? Errors, nothing uploaded, ...? Also, normally you don't check in your /vendor directory into GitHub so I would expect your GH Action file to have a section to install the dependencies. Please edit your question with what is and isn't working and we can help you get set up.

Comment: Not sure if it'll be helpful but here is my master.yml, https://gist.github.com/waterloomatt/fff4fe14f3a3e28b7620a2b1dc602a43

Comment: Hi waterloomatt, If you could tell me how set up Laravel application to shared hosting using Github, it will so help full. I tried to find it on youtube and websites but could not find it. final I bought Laravel forge and cloud hosting because I thought there are no way to deploy Laravel applications using Github. Do you have any guide links please send me. I just want to know how to deploy the Laravel web application using Github.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you're very close but are missing 2 important steps: set up a temporary PHP environment, and use that environment to install your dependencies (Composer).

---

**GitHub Actions Setup**

This guide assumes you have a working Laravel installation, a GitHub account, and a shared hosting account that you can access via FTP using a username/password.

I found this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UNWIXYSZfZY helpful to get a basic understanding of how to deploy a simple application. To make this answer helpful to a wider range of people, I'll give a quick outline of my setup. There really aren't any Laravel-specific steps.

**Workflow directory set up**

Create the directories `.github\workflows` at the root of your project. In the `workflows` directory, create a yml file named after the branch you want to push to your shared hosting account. Ex. `master.yml`, `staging.yml`, `development.yml` etc. If you only have a single branch then just create one file. The name is important and should match the name of the branch.

[image: Screen shot of workflow file]

**Design your workflow**

This is very dependent on your project but assuming you have a basic Laravel application without the need for additional components such as Node, then this is a basic GitHub Action that works for me on a variety of projects.

A basic action file consists of 2 sections, [the *workflow*](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/triggering-a-workflow), and [the *jobs*](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-jobs-in-a-workflow). A workflow triggers the jobs.

**Workflow**

[Lines 1-4](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#on) say this will run each time we `push` to the `master` branch.

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
```

[Line 5](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#name) is the name of this workflow and will show up on your Actions page. Set this to something descriptive.

```
name:  Deploy website on push (Master)
```

**Setting up jobs**

In this section, there are 5 jobs. Some take parameters, others don't. I'm not going to explain all the details here but have linked to the corresponding repositories if you need details.

1. Checkout your code so the workflow has access to it,
   https://github.com/actions/checkout

```
name:  Get latest code
uses: actions/checkout@v2
```

2. Sets up a temporary PHP environment so you can run things like
   Composer, https://github.com/shivammathur/setup-php. Make sure to set your PHP version here otherwise you could run into issues when installing Composer packages with an unexpected PHP version.

```
name: Setup PHP
uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
with:
  php-version: 7.2
```

3. Caches your dependencies for faster deploys,
   https://github.com/actions/cache

```
name: Cache Composer packages
id: composer-cache
uses: actions/cache@v2
with:
  path: vendor
  key: ${{ runner.os }}-php-${{ hashFiles('**/composer.lock') }}
  restore-keys: |
    ${{ runner.os }}-php-
```

4. Install your dependencies from `composer.json` and `composer.lock`
   files.

```
name: Install dependencies
run: composer install --prefer-dist --no-progress
```

5. Deploys your code to your remote shared hosting site,
   https://github.com/SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action. Note the use of `${{ secrets.ftp_username }}` and `${{ secrets.ftp_password }}`. These are set up in your repository's secrets section. See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets

```
name:  Sync files
uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@4.0.0
with:
  server: name_of_server.com
  username: ${{ secrets.ftp_username }}
  password: ${{ secrets.ftp_password }}
  server-dir: public_html/
```

**Final file**

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
name:  Deploy website on push (Master)
jobs:
  web-deploy:
    name:  Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name:  Get latest code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup PHP
        uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
        with:
          php-version: 7.2

      - name: Cache Composer packages
        id: composer-cache
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: vendor
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-php-${{ hashFiles('**/composer.lock') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-php-

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: composer install --prefer-dist --no-progress

      - name:  Sync files
        uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@4.0.0
        with:
          server: name_of_server.com
          username: ${{ secrets.ftp_username }}
          password: ${{ secrets.ftp_password }}
          server-dir: public_html/
```

**Running the workflow**

1. Check-in `.github\workflows\master.yml`, and others if appropriate,
   into your GitHub repository. Without these files checked in nothing
   will happen when you push a change to the branch.
2. Go to your Actions tab and ensure the workflow shows up there.
   [image: Action present]
3. Push a change to your branch and watch the Actions tab. Click into
   the running action to see details about the run. [image: Action details]
4. Fix any errors that show up in the console.

Finally, you mentioned in a comment something about NPM. If you have Node as a component in your project you can simply run two extra steps that will bundle your assets and will get deployed along with the rest of the code.

Good luck!
[image: Node run]

Comment: Hello Waterloomatt, First of all, Thank you very much for this. I think I am doing something wrong because I tried this and successfully deploy it to shared hosting but when go to the domain it is not working. It shows 403 Forbidden error because of Laravel public folder (image is here: https://imgur.com/hfNZYJW ). this is my GitHub repo https://github.com/madushancs/laravel_github_action .

Comment: I tried to deploy it to my dev subdomain. do I need to edit the .htaccess file? When I normally do zip public folder and other folders separately and put public folder files into domain folder and other files put out of the public folder and change index.php __DIR__ path into that such as ..apps/../vendor/autoload.php

Comment: Change your document root to point to the public dir.

Comment: Hey waterloomatt, It is working now. Thanks a lot for the guide me.

Comment: What about running migrations (php artisan migrate)?

Comment: @LeslieJoe, see the post-deploy step, https://gist.github.com/waterloomatt/fff4fe14f3a3e28b7620a2b1dc602a43#file-master-yml-L38

Comment: Okay it may be possible.  What about the configuration for database connection in .env file? Or should I manually add and edit the env file on cPanel for it to migrate tables? I do know that creating a new env file can be done on github action but when making and pushing changes to the repository, it will reset the database configuration to default so running migrations may fail.

Comment: Don't check your .env files in to your source control. They should remain separate.

Answer (score 0):

First : We need to create FTP account on our Cpanel , Open the cpanel then go to FTP accounts then add username , choose the domain and add the password (and make sure there is no special characters and I will tell you why later)

Second : Go to your github repo and then go to Actions sections and choose set up a workflow yourself .
Now we will start writing our own workflow on a YML file which a language to write human-readable data serialization language that is often used for writing configuration files.

we will write this insturctions you will find it on this gist on github

```
on: 
  push:
    branches:
        # Here you can choose the branch you want to update from
      - master
name:  Deploy website on push

jobs:
  web-deploy:
    name:  Deploy website
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    # Checkout the repository
    - name:  Get latest code
      uses: actions/checkout@v4
    # sync files via FTP
    
    - name:  Sync files via FTP
      uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@v4.3.4
        with:
          server: "Server Host"
          username: "FTP UserName"
          password: "FTP password"
          protocol: ftps
```

these instructions contains three main parts

First Part : which is about when to do the deployment (Every Push) ,

and what branch to get the code from and we choosed (master)

Second part : to checkout the repo to git the latest updates.

Third part : to sync the code via ftp account .

now commit then wait until the workflow finishes loading .

Congratsssss   with every push your server will be updated with the latest code base.